# Database has a product called "Kiwi Cubes". Fulltext Search for "Kiwi", "Kiwi Slices", and "Pineapple Cubes" should be returned

Tags: php, mysql

When it comes to creating a search-box, I do not want users to be limited to typing precise sentences in order to find the product they are looking for. If there is a product called "Kiwi Cubes" and I search for "Kiwi Slices", the Kiwi Cubes should still appear.

```
SELECT *
, ( (1.3 * (MATCH(wsp_product_title) AGAINST ('+kiwi+slices' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
  + (0.6 * (MATCH(wsp_product_description) AGAINST ('+kiwi+slices' 
  IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance
FROM webstore_products
LEFT JOIN webstore_product_size_variants ON wsp_product_id = wspsv_product_id 
WHERE wsp_shop_id = 4
AND wspsv_visibility = 2 
AND (MATCH(wsp_product_title,wsp_product_description) AGAINST 
     ('+kiwi+slices' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
GROUP BY wsp_product_id
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Here's a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e13bcf/2

How can I adjust my query to include similar results even if nothing is found?

*N.B. The query successfully returns a value on my server... not sure why the fiddle isn't running.

Comment: You have an error on your sqlfiddle's schema, please try to fix that so it will be easier to test

Comment: I think having a plus sign would make it match both words. If you removed the plus signs, then it will match either word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html shows some examples

Comment: @aynber Ditto. I thought it had to do with my query, did not realize it was the operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to filter results as OP requires: Remove the plus signs then it will match either word - credits to @aynber